# Question on Equivalence of two statements in an Ordered Field

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

In an Ordered Field $\mathbb{F}, \hspace{3mm}LUB \iff IVT$.

Now assuming IVT and Archimedian Property ($\impliedby$ LUB $\iff$ IVT) we can conclude the Existence of the $n^{th}$ root of a positive element in $\mathbb{F}$.

Now is the converse true? I mean:

Does the existence of nth root guarantees IVT or LUB in $\mathbb{F}$?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Take the real algebraic numbers, for example.  We can take $n$-th root of positives, but we are missing all the transcendentals.